# Javascript - extract some numbers in parentheses from text file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text file with the line below:

Numbers: 22,55.000,1(1300.000,1200.999),(1000.888,1222.000),...

I'm using the line below to extract the first number but ideally I only need the numbers in parentheses

```
output=output.split("\n").filter(/./.test, Numbers/).join("\n").replace(/.*?
(([0-9]*\.)?[0-9]+).*/g, "$1");
```

I need to extract the number 1300.00 which is the 4th number after the parentheses

Comment: Did I understand your question correct, or did I miss something. :-D

Comment: I I think I understand now your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the text input looks like this *(string, with each line having the same format)*:
***No comma after the 3rd Number and the bracket `,1(1`***

```
Numbers: 22,55.000,1(1300.000,1200.999),(1000.888,1222.000),...
Numbers: 22,55.000,1(1300.001,1200.999),(1000.888,1222.000),...
...
```

And I assume the output should look like this *(javascript string, not an array)*

```
1300.000
1300.001
```

Then the solution is *(keeping as much as possible of the your original Code)*:

```js
let output =`Numbers: 22,55.000,1(1300.000,1200.999),(1000.888,1222.000),...
Numbers: 22,55.000,1(1300.001,1200.999),(1000.888,1222.000),...
`;
let output0 = output
                .split("\n")
                .filter(/./.test, /Numbers/)
                .join("\n")
                .replace(/[^\(]+\(([^,]+).*/g, "$1\n");
                
// just changing the RegExp
console.info(output0);

// Alternative is to filter the number with the map function
let output1 = output
                .split("\n")
                // My opinion: better/easy to read/understand would be
                // .filter(line => /Number/.test(line))
                .filter(/./.test, /Numbers/)
                .map(line =>
                     line.split(/,|\(|\)/).filter(number => number != "")[3])
                .join("\n");

console.info(output1);
```

**First Version**
changing only the expression, which matches the whole line, but return the 4th Number as group(=first number in parentesis).

**Second Version**
splits by line and than by numbers. In this version is very easy to select single numbers at specific positions.

Comment: outstanding. Thanks a lot for the help! @winner_joiner